# How to pass a string param into an Android XML file?

Tags: java, android, xml

Having a couple issues with this. I'm using a sample Android XML file, and this is the line it uses    `<string name="search_results">\'<xliff:g id="string">%s</xliff:g>\'</string>` which outputs: `'mystring'`

I want it to output just `mystring`, without the quotes. If I take out the quotes in the xml file, I get `s` as the output. If I take out just one, I either get `s'` or `'mystring`, depending on which mark is taken out. To be clear, I am literally getting the letter 's' as the output.

I couldn't find a simple tutorial on this, I figure one of you will know pretty quickly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you happen to try:

```
<string name="search_results"><xliff:g id="string">%s</xliff:g></string>
```

Comment: You are a magical genius, thank you. I'll mark this page so I can come vote you up when I get enough reputation :)

Comment: @ahmet alp balkan. Thanks, figured out how to do that and did :)

Answer (score 1):

What if you take the output with the quotes 'mystring' and then run that through a method that removes the quotes? Something like this:

```
public String removeQuotes(String value){
    if(value.startsWith("\'"){
        value = value.substring(1, value.length());
    }

    if(value.endsWith("\'"){
        value = value.substring(0, value.length()-1);
    }

    return value;

}
```

not sure if that would be feasible solution for you or not but it could be a temp fix if anything.

That code might not work 100% [I'm a tad rusty] just wanted to give an idea though. Hope it helps.